# #ifdef macros vs -Wpedantic and "extra" semicolons

Tags: c++, warnings, preprocessor, clang++

My code-library has a header file that contains this bit of preprocessor magic:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG_OBJECTS
# define DECLARE_DEBUG_OBJECT(v) DebugObject obj(v)
#else
# define DECLARE_DEBUG_OBJECT(v)
#endif
```

The idea is that in various classes in other header files, I can do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() {}

private:
   DECLARE_DEBUG_OBJECT(123);
};
```

... and if I've defined `-DENABLE_DEBUG_OBJECTS` in my Makefile, then `MyClass` will have a `DebugObject` in it as a private member variable, or if I didn't, it won't.

This works fine, except for one minor annoyance -- if I compile my code with clang's `-Wpedantic` flag, and without `-DENABLE_DEBUG_OBJECTS` present, I get lots of warnings about the "extra" semi-colon at in the `private:` section:

```
$ clang++ -Wpedantic ./test.cpp
./test.cpp:14:29: warning: extra ';' inside a class [-Wextra-semi]
DECLARE_DEBUG_OBJECT(123);
```

Now two obvious ways to avoid this would be to disable the extra-semicolons warning, or to put the semi-colon into the #define line instead of keeping it separate in the private: section of `MyClass`.

However, I'm feeling stubborn, and so I'd prefer to keep the semicolon separate (just for aesthetic reasons), and I'd also like to be able to enable `-Wpedantic` without seeing this error pop up all over the place.

So my question is:  Is there some no-op token I can put into the non-ENABLE_DEBUG_OBJECTS branch of the above `#ifdef` that would convince clang++ to not complain about the semicolon, but otherwise be a no-op as far as the compiler is concerned?

Comment: You could try a trivial static assertion, but I'm not sure if that ever produces a warning either.

Comment: Hey, that worked!  Convert your comment to an answer and I'll mark it.   :)   `#define DECLARE_DEBUG_OBJECT(v) static_assert(true, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial static assertion (`static_assert(true, "");`) isn't currently picked up for Clang warnings. That could change with future versions, however.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (works back to C++98) would be `static const int v = 0`. Since this is an integral constant expression, compilers usually don't need to allocate storage for it/ That makes it a true no-overhead no-op.

Comment: or `typedef`, class declaration.